# Connection issue with TLS 1.1 and 1.2 - Azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, tls1.2

In my application I am calling an API written in WebAPI and hosted in a PaaS environment in azure from another WebAPI method (ideally an internal service call), say MethodA in WebApp_A is calling MethodB in WebApp_B. But i am getting the mentioned error if the TLS settings of WebApp_B is either 1.1 or 1.2 ( it works with 1.0). 
"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

I have similar WebApp (WebApp_C) which doesn't have the error with TLS. Below is the code that we use to call the MethodB in WebApp_B from WebApp_A

```
 public async Task<ServiceResponse> CreateDialog(RequestObject requestObject)
 {
        ServiceResponse serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse();
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

                SessionTokenBo jwtData = new SessionTokenBo();
                Logger = _logger;
                jwtData = GetInternalToken(InternalCallTypes.Utilities.ToString(), int.Parse(ServiceConfiguration.TokenExpiryWindow), int.Parse(ServiceConfiguration.InternalTokenExpiryWindow));
                if (null != jwtData)
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("URI");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtData.Token);                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("service/methodB", requestObject);                        
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                        serviceResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponse>(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           throw
        }
        return serviceResponse;
  }
```

If i give Security protocol like this , it will work

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Also i tried from postman with the request and it is not failing. So now am confused because if from postman its working then ideally its not the WebApp setup issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS 1.0 is no longer the default. Add this line before making the request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Have a Reference to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1639).

Update:

> but my doubt is why the same code is not failing for other web apps ?

Found the issue, it was due the target framework was 4.5.2 in webconfig.

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.7.2"></compilation> 
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

Comment: Joey yes i have updated my code. But how come other webapp does not have this issue concerns me.

Comment: TTLS 1.2 was supported in all versions of Postman Native app. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4677).

Comment: i can accept this as answer. I had this code, but my doubt is why the same code is not failing for other web apps ?

Comment: the project framework being 4.7.1 the default TLS is 1.0. I confirmed by capturing the request in Fiddler

Comment: Found the issue, it was due the target framework was 4.5.2 in webconfig.<compilation targetFramework="4.7.2"></compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />